# Como crear ilusion de rotacion orbital con una serie de imagenes en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, animación

Hola amigos necesito agilizar mi trabajo con alguna herramienta javascript o programa que me ayude a dar la ilusion mediante una serie de fotos (frames) que se van mostrando cuadro por cuadro y dar la ilusion que mientras se pasa el mouse se esta rotando alrededor de el edificio ademas de anexarles notas que desplieguen informacion de muestra al usuario de forma interactiva, veo que ya existen un monton de librerias que hacen esto en rotacion 360, pero hasta ahora no encuentro una que lo haga con multiples cuadros de fotos y de forma eliptica como intento en el siguiente link que les dejo. Agradesco la ayuda

https://jcastillovnz.github.io/orbital/

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con la siguiente librería

[three.js](https://threejs.org/)

Está muy completa y tiene muy buena compatibilidad con Blender, para integrar tus diseños.

El tema de JS/Diseño es algo complicado y si te tomará un tiempo.

Te anexo un artículo interesante:

[Importing a Modeled Mesh From Blender to Three.js](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/07/27/importing-blender-modelized-mesh-in-threejs.html)

Comment: el gran problema es que no puedo hacerlo en base a archivos 3d, me dan una serie de imagenes y en base a eso debo hacer la rotacion algo como esto http://axeon.fr/CLIENT/OGIC/Blanc.Mesnil/MAQUETTE_3D/Bati_C/index.html